# What is the function to obtain the length by filling in theta in the following image?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Given this situation, there are 3 colored lines. The green and red line move, and have a constant length, while the blue line gets larger. Because the green and red line have a constant length, we can express their length. I express the length of the green line as $d$, and the length of the red line as $r$.
The angle between the red and white lines is $\theta$. So when the red line rotates, $\theta$ gets larger or smaller, depending on the direction of rotation.

Now my question is, set up a function where you fill in $\theta$ to get the length of the blue line (we define this adjustable length with $s$). You can use the parameters $r$ and $d$. I just can't figure it out with these sides. Do I need more parameters in order to solve the problem?

**What I have tried:**
I've figured out the maximum degree theta can get. Using the cosine rule $d^2 = r^2 + r^2 + 2rr\cos(\theta)$, I can determine that $\theta_{\text{max}}$ is equal to $\arccos(1 - d^2/2r^2)$. Then the domain for theta would become: $[0,\arccos(1 - d^2/2r^2)]$.
It seems that the function is not linear, when mapping it linearly to the length of the blue line: $[0,s]$.

Here is the image of the situation:

[image]

**Note & edit:** length of blue line + white horizontal line = constant, during the rotation of the red line.

Comment: I feel like you'd also need the length of the horizontal and the vertical white lines to solve this, right?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response and reading. The length of the vertical white line is equal to r. The horizontal line idk. But I hope it can be solved without giving any angles than theta, that's my only wish, because then I can apply some physics equations in order to find some lever arm forces with just only theta.

Comment: Another idea I feel, is that I can determine the exact position of the other point of the red rotating line, with `r*sin(theta)` and `r*cos(theta)` to calculate the x- and y-coordinate. But even with that, I cannot determine the x-coordinate of the point intersecting the green and blue line.

Comment: i mean, the blue line could extend arbitrarily to the left, no? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry for the misunderstanding. The blue line doesn't move to the left. The length of the blue line only depends on the displacement of the green line. So in other words, length of the blue line + horizontal white line = constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: sketch]

Okay so we have $|AC|=|AB|=r$, $|CD|=d$, and we want to find $|BD|$ (orange). Then you can subtract $|BD|$ from the 'constant' you mentioned at the end of your post to find the blue line's length.

First, drop a perpendicular from $C$ onto $AB$, and label the intersection $E$. From trigonometry, we have $|AE|=r\cos\theta$ and $|EC|=r\sin\theta$. Now extend $C$ parallel to $AB$, and also extend $BD$, such that these two extensions meet at $F$. Then, $|FC|=|BE|=|AB|-|AE|=r-r\cos\theta$. Since $\angle CFB=90^\circ$ by construction, $|FC|^2+|FD|^2=|CD|^2$, or, $|FD|=\sqrt{d^2-r^2(1-\cos\theta)^2}$. But note that $|FB|=|CE|=r\sin\theta$, and $|BD|=|FD|-|FB|$. So, the orange segment has length $\sqrt{d^2-r^2(1-\cos\theta)^2}-r\sin\theta$. You can use this to find the blue length if you know what orange+blue is.

Comment: Not only is the answer you've obtained correct, but your explanation is also very clear! Thanks a lot! How do you do Latex in equations?

Comment: What do you mean..? Didn't you also use Latex in your question post?

Comment: Oh, now I see. Someone has edited the post! That looks much better.

Comment: If you're asking how to enable/use Latex here specifically, you can just enclose your code in dollar signs